# Wordpress query_posts order by meta-key AND date

Tags: sorting, wordpress

I want to make a query_posts where I order first by the number of a custom field (Facebook Likes) and second by date. But I don't don't know how.

My query looks like that atm:

```
$social_query = array(
'meta_key' => 'facebook_likes',
'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
'order' => 'DESC',
'posts_per_page' => 10,
'paged' => (int) $paged
);
query_posts( $social_query );
```

Now the posts get ordered by the number of facebook-likes. This works fine. But if there are posts with the same number of likes they get sortet randomly and thats the problem. If there are posts with the same number of facebook-likes they should be ordered by date.

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 4):

WordPress allows you to specify more than one `orderby` parameter. To do this, you simply separate each parameter with a blank space. Here is how your new query should look like:

```
$social_query = array(
    'meta_key' => 'facebook_likes',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'paged' => (int) $paged
);
query_posts( $social_query );
```

I'm not sure if this will result in the order that you desire, but that's what WordPress allows you to do with it's in-built function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried your version, but then the posts get only sorted by date and not by face-book likes anymore.

Comment: When I was testing I saw that the order was included in the SQL query(so it was something like `ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_key, wp_posts.date`), but I guess it might not work the way one would expect it to work.

Comment: Ok. And do you know how I get the order I wanna have?

Comment: Since the query doesn't work the way you want it to, you might want to do it in the original way(without the `date` added to the `orderby` argument) and then use a custom function to sort the posts(using the [`usort()`](http://php.net/usort) function. What you would do is to check whether the number of likes is the same for every two posts and if it is you would then check the posts's date and sort by that.